# Shopify allows to add any number of units to cart

Tags: php, html, css, shopify, liquid

In my Shopify website, users are able to add any number of units for a product irrespective of the inventory. The stock is only checked when users click on checkout. How can I handle this issue?

Ideally, users should be able to add only available inventory to the cart. It's annoying when someone adds multiple quantities only to know they aren't in stock.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the `variant.inventory_quantity` => https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/variant#variant-inventory_quantity

If you have no option you can get it like so `product.first_available_variant.inventory_quantity`.

But if you have multiply options you will need to loop all the variants and create a JS object that will store each variant `inventory_quantity` and perform a JS check or update the max attribute of the number input for the quantity before adding the product to the cart.